# How do I operate on groups returned by Dask's group by?

Tags: dask

I have the following table.

```
    value   category
0   2       A
1   20      B
2   4       A
3   40      B
```

I want to add a `mean` column that contains the mean of the values for each category.

```
    value   category  mean
0   2       A          3.0
1   20      B         30.0
2   4       A          3.0
3   40      B         30.0
```

I can do this in pandas like so

```
p = pd.DataFrame({"value":[2, 20, 4, 40], "category": ["A", "B", "A", "B"]})
groups = []
for _, group in p.groupby("category"):
    group.loc[:,"mean"] = group.loc[:,"value"].mean()
    groups.append(group)
pd.concat(groups).sort_index()
```

How do I do the same thing in Dask?

I can't use the pandas functions as-is because you can't enumerate over a groupby object in Dask. This

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

d = dd.from_pandas(p, chunksize=100)
list(d.groupby("category"))
```

raises `KeyError: 'Column not found: 0'`.

I can use an `apply` function to calculate the mean in Dask.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

d = dd.from_pandas(p, chunksize=100)
q = d.groupby(["category"]).apply(lambda group: group["value"].mean(), meta="object")
q.compute()
```

returns

```
category
A     3.0
B    30.0
dtype: float64
```

But I can't figure how how to fold these back into the rows of the original table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a merge to achieve this operation:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': [2, 20, 4, 40],
    'category': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)

# Lazy-compute mean per category
mean_by_category = (ddf
                   .groupby('category')
                   .agg({'value': 'mean'})
                   .rename(columns={'value': 'mean'})
                   ).persist()
mean_by_category.head()

# Assign 'mean' value to each corresponding category
ddf = ddf.merge(mean_by_category, left_on='category', right_index=True)
ddf.head()
```

Which should then output:

```
  category  value  mean
0        A      2   3.0
2        A      4   3.0
1        B     20  30.0
3        B     40  30.0
```